# How to use eclipse's code formatter to remove new lines after 'case'?

Tags: eclipse, format, switch-statement

I looked in the eclipse Java formatter (Java / Code Style / Formatter) but could not find a way to not have a new line after `case`. Instead of

```
switch (a) {
    case 0:
        Other.doFoo();
        break;
    case 1:
        Other.doBaz();
}
```

I want

```
switch (a) {
    case 0: Other.doFoo();
            break;
    case 1: Other.doBaz();
}
```

Is there a way to do it and if so what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found no way to resolve this. There is no way of **refractoring existing code** as you expected.

But you can avoid writing such switch statement now onwards by enabling **off/on** tags as explained here [Eclipse Formatter Allow Multi Line ;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110992/eclipse-formatter-allow-multi-line/23192971#23192971) and then changing the **switch** template in `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editors > Templates` as mentioned below

```
    //@formatter:off
        switch (${key}) {
            case ${value}:${cursor}
                          break;

            default:break;
        }
    //@formatter:on
```

Comment: So this template will be the initial form of the statement, and if I just `ctrl+shift+F` then it will revert to my formatter's structure? By the way, this is **formatting existing code**, not **refactoring existing code**.

Comment: On pressing `Ctrl+Shift+F` will **NOT** format the lines between `@formatter` tags. Test it.

Comment: Tested, the switch is still formatted when I put the tags exactly as you said.

Comment: OK, the `Off/On Tags` need to be enabled in the formatter customization.