# Is there a setting to prevent Eclipse's formatter from inlining statements declared as blocks?

Tags: eclipse

I can't seem to find the formatter settings to prevent Eclipse from putting block style declarations on the same line.

For example, if I type the code like this:

```
private string[] myData={
    "someValue1",
    "someValue2",
    "someValue3",
    "someValue4",
    "someValue5",
    "someValue5"
}
```

Upon running Eclipse's Auto Formatter, the previous declaration then looks like:

```
private string[] myData={
    "someValue1", "someValue2", "someValue3", "someValue4", "someValue5", "someValue5"};
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse conditional formatting braces only for multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665247/eclipse-conditional-formatting-braces-only-for-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to your formatter profile to the tab "Line Wrapping".
- on the list (left) you choose "Array initializers" from "Expressions".
- then bellow the list you choose "Wrap all elements, every element on a new line" from the "Line wrapping policy":

Comment: Almost a good answer. This forces Eclipse to do wrap for array initializers with every element on a new line. The OP asked for something different however - to prevent joining in block declarations. That is achievable on the same panel, by clicking "Never join already wrapped lines"

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the formatter by adding these tags:

```
//@formatter:off
private string[] myData = {
    "someValue1",
    "someValue2",
    "someValue3",
    "someValue4",
    "someValue5",
    "someValue5"
}
//@formatter:on
```